# PHP doesn't work on virtual host in EC2 + ubuntu + apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

PHP doesn't work.

Development environment is the below.

- EC2 Server
- Apache/2.4.7
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9

If I set DocumentRoot `/var/www/html`, php works well.

On the other hand if I set `/home/ubuntu/public_html`, php doesn't work, but html works.

```
$ vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by the below method.

sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf

▼Before

php_admin_flag engine Off

▼Change

php_admin_flag engine On